# Can I use Swift's map() on Protocols?

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-protocols

I have some model code where I have some `Thought`s that i want to read and write to plists. I have the following code:

```
protocol Note {
    var body: String { get }
    var author: String { get }
    var favorite: Bool { get set }
    var creationDate: Date { get }
    var id: UUID { get }
    var plistRepresentation: [String: Any] { get }
    init(plist: [String: Any])
}

struct Thought: Note {
    let body: String
    let author: String
    var favorite: Bool
    let creationDate: Date
    let id: UUID
}

extension Thought {
    var plistRepresentation: [String: Any] {
        return [
            "body": body as Any,
            "author": author as Any,
            "favorite": favorite as Any,
            "creationDate": creationDate as Any,
            "id": id.uuidString as Any
        ]
    }

    init(plist: [String: Any]) {
        body = plist["body"] as! String
        author = plist["author"] as! String
        favorite = plist["favorite"] as! Bool
        creationDate = plist["creationDate"] as! Date
        id = UUID(uuidString: plist["id"] as! String)!
    }
}
```

for my data model, then down in my data write controller I have this method:

```
func fetchNotes() -> [Note] {
    guard let notePlists = NSArray(contentsOf: notesFileURL) as? [[String: Any]] else {
        return []
    }
    return notePlists.map(Note.init(plist:))
}
```

For some reason the line `return notePlists.map(Note.init(plist:))` gives the error `'map' produces '[T]', not the expected contextual result type '[Note]'`
However, If I replace the line with `return notePlists.map(Thought.init(plist:))` I have no issues. Clearly I can't map the initializer of a protocol? Why not and what's an alternate solution?

Comment: Why would you need that? This would be the same as trying to return a `FloatingPoint` object instead of returning a `Double`. It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Btw your struct `Thought`  doesn't conform to your `Note` protocol

Comment: @LeoDabus I forgot the extension, no wonder that didn't make sense. Check out the edit.

Comment: Still doesn't make any sense. How you would expect your initializer to work. There is no Self. A protocol has no initializer. You can't have an instance of your protocol

Comment: You can have many types conforming to the same protocol. All of them are required to implement their own custom initializer. How would you expect the compiler to decide which one to use?

Comment: @LeoDabus Yeah I get it now. So I guess now my question is what would be a simple way to figure out which Note type the dictionary represents and cast accordingly, all within a closure provided to map()?

Comment: Well you are not providing enough information about your actual problem. You are only showing one type. You need to restructure your question.

Comment: I think what you need is to add an enumeration to your protocol with all your note types

Comment: I have just one type for now

Comment: So if you expect to have multiple types conforming to Note you can add an enumeration with a single case for now

Comment: `enum NoteType {
    case thought
}`

Comment: add it to your protocol. `var noteType: NoteType { get }` and add it to your Note objects `struct Thought: Note {
    let noteType: NoteType = .thought`

Comment: This way you can read this property from your dictionary and act accordingly

Comment: Yeah I get where you're going. I have a private method that returns the appropriate Note type using the enum. Post an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: done if you need further help let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you expect to have multiple types conforming to Note and would like to know which type of note it is stored in your dictionary you need to add an enumeration to your protocol with all your note types.

```
enum NoteType {
    case thought 
}
```

add it to your protocol.

```
protocol Note {
    var noteType: NoteType { get }
    // ...
}
```

and add it to your Note objects:

```
 struct Thought: Note {
     let noteType: NoteType = .thought
     // ...
  }
```

This way you can read this property from your dictionary and map it accordingly.